# skipNBytes overrides nothing when creating a descendant from InputStream in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm creating a delegator for an InputStream instance so I want to create a class that overrides all methods of InputStream.

I'm getting a compilation error when I do that:

`'skipNBytes' overrides nothing`
and `Unresolved reference: skipNBytes`

The signature for the method in my Kotlin class looks like this:

```java
    override fun skipNBytes(n: Long) {
        super.skipNBytes(n)
    }
```

This was generated for me by my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA).

I've read other questions related to this and they all suggest making either the return value and/or parameter values nullable but this can't be the case here since the return value is void and the parameter value in the Java InputStream is the long primitive (non-nullable). Besides, I've tried making the parameter `n: Long?` and that does not fix the problem.

So I'm pretty stumped as to what's causing this.

I should note that I'm building this using Gradle using Java 11 and the kotlin plugin version 1.3.72.

Here's a stripped down example of a class that won't compile:

```java
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream

class TestInputStream: InputStream() {
    override fun read(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun read(b: ByteArray): Int {
        return super.read(b)
    }

    override fun read(b: ByteArray, off: Int, len: Int): Int {
        return super.read(b, off, len)
    }

    override fun close() {
        super.close()
    }

    override fun readAllBytes(): ByteArray {
        return super.readAllBytes()
    }

    override fun readNBytes(len: Int): ByteArray {
        return super.readNBytes(len)
    }

    override fun readNBytes(b: ByteArray?, off: Int, len: Int): Int {
        return super.readNBytes(b, off, len)
    }

    override fun skip(n: Long): Long {
        return super.skip(n)
    }

    override fun skipNBytes(n: Long) {
        super.skipNBytes(n)
    }

    override fun available(): Int {
        return super.available()
    }

    override fun mark(readlimit: Int) {
        super.mark(readlimit)
    }

    override fun reset() {
        super.reset()
    }

    override fun markSupported(): Boolean {
        return super.markSupported()
    }

    override fun transferTo(out: OutputStream?): Long {
        return super.transferTo(out)
    }
}
```

And the error I get is:

```
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/stefan/tmp/istest/src/main/kotlin/TestInputStream.kt: (37, 5): 'skipNBytes' overrides nothing
e: /Users/stefan/tmp/istest/src/main/kotlin/TestInputStream.kt: (38, 15): Unresolved reference: skipNBytes

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I can "fix" this by removing the delegation of that one function... but that can be dangerous since then the delegation won't work for any derived classes so I don't want to do that.

Comment: `skipNBytes` was added in Java 12.

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake! I feel very stupid now.

Comment: But why isn't there a @since field on it in the JavaDoc? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#skipNBytes(long)